# When resizing, div down to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

The page has only one photo in the center and some texts. Added a Media Query so that when the viewport is less than 700px it magnifies images, maaas to reduce my screen, it explodes ... and down to the bottom.

How to solve?

CSS:

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background: #181A1B;
}

 p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', san-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #C5C5C7;
  line-height: 14px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}



.block {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #181A1B;

}




.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #181A1B;


}

.centered {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #181A1B;
    max-width: 500px;
    /* width: 100%;  BUUUUGA*/ 

}


.contato ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.contato ul li{
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline; 
}

.contato ul li a{
  display: inline-block;  
}


.img_sprite1 {

  width: 40px;
  height: 38px;

  background-image: url('../img/sprite.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.img_sprite1:hover{

  background-position: 0 -40px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}


.img_sprite2 {

  width: 40px;
  height: 38px;

  background-position: -49px 0;
  background-image: url('../img/sprite.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: 0.5s;

}

.img_sprite2:hover{

  background-position: -49px -40px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.img_sprite3 {

  width: 40px;
  height: 38px;

  background-position: -98px 0;
  background-image: url('../img/sprite.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.img_sprite3:hover{

  background-position: -98px -40px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}


@media screen and (max-width:700px) {


        .block {
          background: #181A1B;

            }




        .block:before {
          content: '';
          display: inline-block;
          background: #181A1B;


        }

         .centered {
             border: 1px solid green;
            width: 100%; 



        } 

        .contato {
            margin-top: 40px;
        }

        .contato ul li {

            margin-right: 30px;
        }  

        .img_sprite1 {

          width: 63px;
          height: 65px;

          background-image: url('../img/sprite2.png');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          transition: 0.5s;
        }

        .img_sprite1:hover{

          background-position: 0 -70px;
          transition: 0.2s;
        }

        .img_sprite2 {

          width: 63px;
          height: 65px;

          background-position: -70px 0;
          background-image: url('../img/sprite2.png');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          transition: 0.5s;

        }

        .img_sprite2:hover{

          background-position: -70px -69px;
          transition: 0.2s;
        }

        .img_sprite3 {

          width: 63px;
          height: 65px;

          background-position: -140px 0;
          background-image: url('../img/sprite2.png');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          transition: 0.5s;

        }

        .img_sprite3:hover{

          background-position: -140px -69px;
          transition: 0.2s;
        }

         p {
          font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', san-serif;
          font-size: 19px;
          color: #C5C5C7;
          line-height: 22px;
          margin-top: 30px;
        }



}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="block">

    <div class="centered">
       <img src="img/img1.jpg"  id="img_logo">


     <div class="contato">
       <ul>
          <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="img_sprite1"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="img_sprite2"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="img_sprite3"></a></li>
          </ul>
     </div> 



        <p> <a style="font-size:35px;"> test </a> <br> Test 2  </p>

    </div>




</div>
```

Comment: Please explain this part a bit better: "_when the viewport is less than 700px it magnifies images, maaas to reduce my screen, it explodes ... and down to the bottom_". It is really difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle or pen for this issue? I can't replicate it, because I don't have the images, and it's hard to understand.

Comment: agoravai2.esy.es put the site on a free server. The main problem is when access through the mobile phone. The desktop is perfect, but when cellphone access it is very, very small. How do I solve this problem of "size"?